# What Does CAS Mean On Sims 4?

Tags: terminology, the-sims-4

I'm so confused, everybody is saying it on youtube and the internet, I have no idea what it means! Can anybody help?

Answer (score 4):

CAS stands for Create a Sim. That is where you create your Sims and make families and such.